# Rename one named column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to update one column of a dataframe, referencing it using its original name, is this possible? For example say I had the table 'data'

```
a b c  
1 2 2  
3 2 3  
4 1 2
```

and I wanted to update the name of column b to 'd'. I know I could use

```
colnames(data)[2] <- 'd'
```

but can I make the change by specifically referencing b, i.e. something like

```
colnames(data)['b'] <- 'd'
```

so that if the column ordering of the dataframe changes the correct column name will still be updated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Good question! Was trying this: `colnames(data['b']) <- 'd'`, also not good! As Chase points out, this is the way: `colnames(data)[colnames(data) == "b"] <- "d"`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of October 2014 this can now be done easily in the [dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) package:

```
rename(data, d = b)
```

Answer (score 30):

There is a function `setnames` built into package [`data.table`](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/) for exactly that.

```
setnames(DT, "b", "d")
```

It changes the names by reference with no copy at all. Any other method using `names(data)<-` or `names(data)[i]<-` or similar will copy the *entire* object, usually several times. Even though all you're doing is changing a column name.

`DT` must be type `data.table` for `setnames` to work, though. So you'd need to switch to `data.table` or convert using `as.data.table`, to use it.

Here is the extract from `?setnames`. The intention is that you run `example(setnames)` at the prompt and then the comments relate to the copies you see being reported by `tracemem`.

```
DF = data.frame(a=1:2,b=3:4)       # base data.frame to demo copies
tracemem(DF)
colnames(DF)[1] <- "A"             # 4 copies of entire object
names(DF)[1] <- "A"                # 3 copies of entire object
names(DF) <- c("A", "b")           # 2 copies of entire object
`names<-`(DF,c("A","b"))           # 1 copy of entire object
x=`names<-`(DF,c("A","b"))         # still 1 copy (so not print method)

# What if DF is large, say 10GB in RAM. Copy 10GB just to change a column name?

DT = data.table(a=1:2,b=3:4,c=5:6)
tracemem(DT)
setnames(DT,"b","B")               # by name; no match() needed. No copy.
setnames(DT,3,"C")                 # by position. No copy.
setnames(DT,2:3,c("D","E"))        # multiple. No copy.
setnames(DT,c("a","E"),c("A","F")) # multiple by name. No copy.
setnames(DT,c("X","Y","Z"))        # replace all. No copy.
```

Comment: But is loading of new package worth all the hustle for the sake of simple column renaming? =)

Comment: Absolutely. It can make the difference between `out of memory`, or not. And it's shorter, easier and slightly less chance of bugs.

Comment: I'd say it depends on how much extra RAM you have laying around

Comment: @Matthew why would renaming columns be hard on memory?  In my example yes but you could easily do a global assignment in the function and pass just column names to the function to avoid this.

Comment: In your scenario the 10G is the dataframe size not the size of the vector of names

Comment: @Tyler Yes. The _entire_ 10GB is copied, just to change the column names. It's crazy isn't it. That's why people don't use R.  You cannot easily avoid it, no.  Do some testing and see. In the first example in the `colnames<-` variant, 10GB gets copies 4 times, so 40GB are churned through. That's why `data.frame` doesn't scale for large data. But `data.table` does.

Comment: @Tyler The reason why is dispatch via `*tmp*`. All assignments of the form `fun()<-` and `fun()[]<-` go via `*tmp*` which is a copy of the entire object. IIUC.

Comment: @Tyler There are two (rather long) threads on r-devel about this: [speeding up perception](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/speeding-up-perception-tp3640920.html) and (perhaps most relevant) [confused about NAMED](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Confused-about-NAMED-tp4103326.html) and probably others.

Comment: Thanks for the links, very informative.  This may be why data.table often benchmarks slower than other methods in that its primary design is for memory issues not speed issues.  Is this correct?

Comment: PS I wouldn't say "this is why people don't use R".  People do.  It's a terrific tool that is useful to many people.  It's not the right tool for every job though; that's what Julia is for :)

Comment: @Tyler Sorry I missed one word: "[some] people". I think it and the community is terrific too which is why I use it.

Comment: @Tyler Now on these benchmarks that show data.table is slower, can you point me to just one please?

Comment: @MatthewDowle -- Just added one more `tracemem` test to your example, just b/c it's kind of hilarious how variable R's behavior is, and b/c I kind of like the count down of `4, 3, 2, 1, ... data.table` .

Comment: @Matthew here's one: [LINK1](http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/22754-Create-a-fast-dictionary?p=72587&viewfull=1#post72587)  I've been benchmarking data.table on many different occasions (10ish) and only once (when aggregating) did data.table come up fastest.

Comment: Perhaps they're being implemented incorrectly so I'll try to find more examples and you can tell me if that's so but this should proably be moved to wiki.

Comment: @Matthew try benchmarking this post: `DF = data.frame(a=1:2,b=3:4,c=5:6)`
`DFmeth <- function() names(DF)[3] <- "C"`

`DT = data.table(a=1:2,b=3:4,c=5:6)`
`DTmeth <- function()setnames(DT,3,"C")`

Comment: @Tyler Are you repeating the call may times in the benchmark? If you don't repeat are the two times 0.000 vs 0.000? `names<-` is a primitive built into R, where `setnames` is an R function in a package. Rather than repeating the call many times before any difference can be noticed, the way to scale it is to increase the size of `DF` and compare the time of a _single run_ as `nrow(DF)` increases.

Comment: @Tyler On your LINK1 I joined that forum and replied. I couldn't see any `data.table` code posted there, so I can't check if it was used correctly, or how the timing was done. However, there were major changes in v1.8.0 (after that thread) for character columns in keys, so please try again with v1.8.0.  More examples / wiki would be great.

Comment: @Josh Thanks for extra line showing `names<-` copying twice. Have added it back to the help file. The right people (r-devel) know about all this because I checked with them first in those threads, so hopefully one day it'll get fixed in R itself. I had a look myself to try and make a patch for R but the `*tmp*` and `NAMED` stuff is beyond my ability.

Answer (score 13):

This seems like a hack, but the first thing that came to mind was to use `grepl()` with a sufficiently detailed enough search string to only get the column you want. I'm sure there are better options:

```
dat <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 1:3, c = 1:3)
colnames(dat)[grepl("b", colnames(dat))] <- "foo"
dat
#------
  a foo c
1 1   1 1
2 2   2 2
3 3   3 3
```

As Joran points out below, I overcomplicated things...no need for a regex at all. This saves a few characters on the typing too.

```
colnames(dat)[colnames(dat) == "foo"] <- "bar"
#------
  a bar c
1 1   1 1
2 2   2 2
3 3   3 3
```

Comment: Or you could simply index the column names using `colnames(dat) == 'b'`, but its going to be circular no matter what you do.

Comment: Don't use regexes for simple stuff like this. I'd rather stick with simple `==` relational operator.

Comment: I thought on first glance that Chase used `agrep` which could have some advantages.

Comment: @aL3xa, if you have many similar column prefixes/suffixes to rename, `gsub` is invaluable. But yeah one isolated case is generally overkill.

Answer (score 4):

Yes but it's more difficult (as far as I know) than numeric indexing.  I'm going to provide a dirty function that will do this and if you want to see how to do it just tear the function apart line by line:

```
rename <- function(df, column, new){
    x <- names(df)                               #Did this to avoid typing twice
    if (is.numeric(column)) column <- x[column]  #Take numeric input by indexing
    names(df)[x %in% column] <- new              #What you're interested in
    return(df)
}

#try it out
rename(mtcars, 'mpg', 'NEW')
rename(mtcars, 1, 'NEW')
```

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with @Chase - the `grepl` solution ain't the luckiest one. I'd say: go with simple `==`. Here's why:

```
d <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), 10))
colnames(d) <- replicate(10, paste(sample(letters[1:5], size = 5, replace=TRUE, prob=c(.1, .6, .1, .1, .1)), collapse = ""))
```

Now try doing `grepl("b", colnames(d))`. Either pass `fixed = TRUE`, or even better do simple `colnames(d) == "b"` like @joran suggested. Regex matching will **always** be slower than `==`, so for simple tasks like this you may want to use simple `==`.

Comment: I think I pointed out in my answer that I was sure there are better answers, specifically the part `I'm sure there are better options`. As Joran pointed out in the comments, directly using `==` is better, which I recognize and show an example of in my answer now too :) I'll leave the top half for posterity's sake.

Comment: This answer is essentially the same as mine in that I use `colnames(d) %in% "b"`.  In this case they're doing the same thing, though I suppose the `==` will be faster.