# Why does changing a column name take an extremely long time with a large data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a `data.frame` in R with 19 million rows and 90 columns. I have plenty of spare RAM and CPU cycles. It seems that changing a single column name in this data frame is a very intense operation for R.

```
system.time(colnames(my.df)[1] <- "foo")
   user  system elapsed 
 356.88   16.54  373.39
```

Why is this so? Does every row store the column name somehow? Is this creating an entirely new data frame? It seems this operation should complete in negligible time. I don't see anything obvious in the [R manual entry](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/colnames.html).

I'm running build 7600 of R (64bit) on Windows 7, and in my current workspace, setting colnames on a small data.frame takes '0' time according to `system.time()`.

Edit: I'm aware of the possibility of using `data.table`, and, honestly, I can wait 5 minutes for the rename to complete whilst I go get some tea. What I'm interested in is **what is happening and why?**

Comment: Oddly, I was just reading about this. I believe it may actually be copying the df _twice_. If you're using 2.15.0, try installing and loading the package **dataframe** and see if that helps any.

Comment: Matthew Dowle explains this very nicely [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655438/rename-one-named-column-in-r/10655997#10655997) and provides a solution with `data.table` package.

Comment: Thanks, I already use `data.table` quite a lot (and am indebted to Matthew Dowle for getting me out of sticky situations!) - here I was after an explanation of what is happening...and ideally why. Is the answer really just "data.frame is badly coded"?

Comment: @ina - for this particular task (renaming columns), perhaps the answer is yes. At Matthew points out, sometimes you won't just have to wait a while, but you may also run out of memory to do something as simple as changing the name.

Comment: @Ina I'm sure you didn't mean anything by it, but I try to be careful about saying that something is "badly coded" when it's written by volunteers, and it's only one piece of a very large/complex piece of software that I find enormously helpful. R Core members surely get far more complaints than thanks. (Though I agree, it is pretty crazy that it copies the df that many times just to change the names.)

Comment: Spot on @joran - and it could be that there's a very good reason it has to take that long to enable something else. Hopefully none of the authors will read my comment :)

Comment: It is not badly coded, just inefficient especially if you use the wrong combination of functions as Josh via Matthew Dowle illustrate. A point I haven't seen mentioned is R's functional programming paradigm where a function should not change its arguments. Hence `"names<-"()` must return an object that is a copy of its input with the updated names, *even* if this means copying the entire data frame. It isn't allowed to modify the object passed to it. Now R is usually quite clever and tries not to copy until you modify an object but as soon as you do, copies will occur.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As several commenters have mentioned, renaming data frame columns is slow, because (depending on how you do it) it makes between 1 and 4 copies of *the entire data.frame*. Here, from `data.table`'s `?setkey` help page, is the nicest way of demonstrating this behavior that I've seen:

```
DF = data.frame(a=1:2,b=3:4)       # base data.frame to demo copies
try(tracemem(DF))                  # try() for non-Windows where R is 
                                   # faster without memory profiling
colnames(DF)[1] <- "A"             # 4 copies of entire object
names(DF)[1] <- "A"                # 3 copies of entire object
names(DF) <- c("A", "b")           # 1 copy of entire object
`names<-`(DF,c("A","b"))           # 1 copy of entire object
x=`names<-`(DF,c("A","b"))         # still 1 copy (so not print method)
# What if DF is large, say 10GB in RAM. Copy 10GB just to change a column name?
```

To (start) understanding **why** things are done this way, you'll probably need to delve into some of the related discussions on R-devel. Here are a couple: [R-devel: speeding up perception](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/speeding-up-perception-td3640920.html) and [R-devel: Confused about NAMES](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Confused-about-NAMED-td4103326.html)

My impressionistic reading of those threads is that:

1. At least one copy is made so that modifications to it can be 'tried out' before overwriting the original. Thus, if something is wrong with the value-to-be-reassigned, `[<-.data.frame` or `names<-` can 'back out' and deliver an error message without having done any damage to the original object.
2. Several members of R-core aren't completely satisfied with how things are working right now. Several folks explain that in some cases "R loses track"; Luke Tierney indicates that he's tried some modifications relating to this copying in the past "in a few cases and always had to back off"; and Simon Urbanek hints that "there may be some things coming up, too"

(As I said, though, that's just impressionistic: I'm simply not able to follow a full conversation about the details of R's internals!)

---

Also relevant, in case you haven't seen it, here's how something like `names(z)[3] <- "c2"` "really" works:

```
# From ?names<-
z <- "names<-"(z, "[<-"(names(z), 3, "c2"))
```

---

**Note:** Much of this answer comes from Matthew Dowle's answer to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655438/rename-one-named-column-in-r/10655997#10655997). (I thought it was worth placing it here, and giving it some more exposure, since it's so relevant to your own question).

Comment: ++ for parsing the R-devel threads, I was having a hard time wrapping my head around those conversations.